# How to align labels to the inside edge of polar bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am stuck making the visualization I want. I cannot yet put images so the link is below. I almost have what I want. The issue is the labels are not correctly placed.

inverted-polar-bar-demo

[image]

I would like to have the labels be rotated like they are, but have the labels' right edges aligned to just inside the outer edge of the circle.

**EDIT** To clarify:
The labels I used for this example are all 'testing'. With actual data, these labels will be of different length. I want to have the end of the labels moved so that they always have their last letter next to the outside edge of the circle. So in this case, all the 'g's would be next to the outside edge.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
import numpy as np
import random

bgcolor = '#222222'
barcolor = '#6699cc'
bottom = 15

N = 32
Values = np.random.random(N)*10
MetricLabels = ['testing' for _ in range(1, N+1)]

# Select the radii, thetas, and widths.
Radii = -5*np.ones(N)-Values
Theta = np.linspace(0.0, 2 * np.pi, N, endpoint=False)
width = 2*np.pi/N

# Make a list of shifted thetas to place the labels at.
ThetaShifted = np.copy(Theta)
for i in range(N-1):
    ThetaShifted[i] = (Theta[i] + Theta[i+1])/2.0
ThetaShifted[-1] = (Theta[-1] + 2.0*np.pi)/2.0

# Make the figure
fig = mpl.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
bars = ax.bar(Theta, Radii, width=width, bottom=bottom)

# Set the outer ring to be invisible.
ax.spines["polar"].set_visible(False)

# Set the grid line locations but set the labels to be invisible.
ax.grid(False)
ax.set_thetagrids([], visible=False)
ax.set_rgrids([3], visible=False)

# Apply colors to bars based on the settings above.
for v, bar in zip(Values, bars):
        bar.set_facecolor(barcolor)
        bar.set_edgecolor(bar.get_facecolor())

# Show the metric and value labels
for counter in range(N):
    ax.text(ThetaShifted[counter], bottom-3, MetricLabels[counter], 
            horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='baseline', 
            rotation=(counter+.5)*360/N, color=bgcolor)
    ax.text(ThetaShifted[counter], bottom+0.75, np.round(Values[counter],2), 
            horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', 
            color=bars[counter].get_facecolor())

# Set the background color to be a dark grey,
ax.set_axis_bgcolor(bgcolor)
fig.set_facecolor(bgcolor)

# Show the figure.
mpl.show()
```

Comment: If you solved your own, issue, you can post it as an answer to your own question. It's a lot easier to discover for future people rather than reading your "question" looking for the answer `;)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually solved my issue. See image and code below. The main thing to solve it was to use the monospace font family and to use rjust to create the label strings to be fixed length and right justified from the beginning. After that, it is just a matter of choosing the correct radial location for each label which should be much easier when they are all the same number of characters.

[image: Initial demo solved]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
import numpy as np
import random

bgcolor = '#222222'
barcolor = '#6699cc'
bottom = 15

N = 32
Values = np.random.random(N)*10
MetricLabels = [('A'*(4+int(8*random.random()))).rjust(10) for _ in range(1, N+1)]

# Select the radii, thetas, and widths.
Radii = -5*np.ones(N)-Values
Theta = np.linspace(0.0, 2 * np.pi, N, endpoint=False)
width = 2*np.pi/N

# Make a list of shifted thetas to place the labels at.
ThetaShifted = np.copy(Theta)
for i in range(N-1):
    ThetaShifted[i] = (Theta[i] + Theta[i+1])/2.0
ThetaShifted[-1] = (Theta[-1] + 2.0*np.pi)/2.0

# Make the figure
fig = mpl.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
bars = ax.bar(Theta, Radii, width=width, bottom=bottom)

# Set the outer ring to be invisible.
ax.spines["polar"].set_visible(False)

# Set the grid line locations but set the labels to be invisible.
ax.grid(False)
ax.set_thetagrids([], visible=False)
ax.set_rgrids([3], visible=False)

# Apply colors to bars based on the settings above.
for v, bar in zip(Values, bars):
    bar.set_facecolor(barcolor)
    bar.set_edgecolor(bar.get_facecolor())

# Show the metric and value labels
for counter in range(N):
    ax.text(ThetaShifted[counter], bottom-.075*(10+len(MetricLabels[counter])), MetricLabels[counter]+' '*5, 
            horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', 
            rotation=(counter+.5)*360/N, color=bgcolor,
            family='monospace')
    ax.text(ThetaShifted[counter], bottom+1, np.round(Values[counter],2), 
            horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', 
            rotation=(counter+.5)*360/N, color=bars[counter].get_facecolor(),
            family='monospace')

# Set the background color to be a dark grey,
ax.set_axis_bgcolor(bgcolor)
fig.set_facecolor(bgcolor)

# Show the figure.
mpl.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

If I correct understand what you want you have to add `rotation` property to the second call of `counter` cycle and align the text like here:

```
...
# Show the metric and value labels
for counter in range(N):
    ax.text(ThetaShifted[counter], bottom-3, MetricLabels[counter], 
            horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='baseline', 
            rotation=(counter+.5)*360/N, color=bgcolor)
    ax.text(ThetaShifted[counter], bottom+2.5, np.round(Values[counter],2), 
            horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', 
            rotation=(counter+.5)*360/N, 
            color=bars[counter].get_facecolor())
 ...
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reminder to rotate the numbers too. However, what I wanted was to have all the 'g's be next to the outside edge.